# HTML parents - Unsure of how to use CSS percentages properly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with understanding how to properly use the percentage height property in CSS.
It has been a useful tool for me in the past, when sizing elements with respect to the page size.

However I have come across a problem when using percentages to specify properties of divs within divs.

For example,

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
     Hello
  </div>
</div
```

In the above code, I set the text of the "inner" class to have a top-margin of 5%, which successfully pushes the text down from the top edge of the "outer" class.

However, I was told that the 5% would be relative to the parent of the element, which I would assume would be "outer" (because it is within the outer div tags). It actually acts as 5% of the page height, which pushes it down much further than intended.

I'm probably missing some quirk of HTML/CSS, because I'm still relatively new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

edit: I now understand that the problem lies on certain parent elements not having static dimensions, however is there a way to avoid this but still have relative heights/widths on child elements? It would seem silly to define the body with a static height/width, which would just seriously limit the site's accessibility on devices with other dimensions.

Relevant CSS code for "outer" (bear in mind I just used outer/inner as examples, and below is the actual code I've been using)

```
.login_center_panel
{
   width:50%;
   height:30%;
   background-color:#3D3D3D;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   float:top;
   border-top-left-radius: 15px;
   border-top-right-radius: 15px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
   font-family: "Verdana", Arial, sans-serrif;
   color:white;
   padding:1px;
}
```

and below is the relevant css for "inner"

```
#signinGreetText
{
   margin-top:5%;
}
```

The margin-top property of signinGreetText still acts as 5% of the whole page, and not as 5% of the height of login_center_panel

Comment: Can you post the relevant CSS code?

Comment: The 5% should be relative to the last parent element, that defined a height in `px` or a child of that, defining in `%`. So you have the `html/body` probably...

Comment: Isn't it best to avoid ever defining a height/width in pixels though? Wouldn't that just largely restrict how view-able the site is on devices of varying dimensions?

Comment: You would have to define a `html,body{height:100%;width:100%}` and go from there!!

Comment: @LcSalazar I have now added the relevant CSS code

Answer (score 2):

The % is based on the ***width*** of the containing element. You need to specify a width or max-width property for your .outer div or use a different measurement for your top margin. 
To see how the % is based on the width change the width of the page while viewing your current code. The top margin should change with the width of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a height set for 'outer'? If not, this is why the margin is bigger than you expected. If you set a height for 'outer' you will notice the margin will scale accordingly.

Comment: Yes, although the height of outer is also a percentage

Comment: What is the parent that has a specific height set to it, if any? If there is no parent with a height set, this is the reason for your problem. The % height's you have will keep going up to the next parent to determine its height. If it does not find one at the end of all elements, it will use 100%.

Comment: Try setting a fixed height on the parent of the div where you need the child to have a % height.

Comment: I've been told this, however I feel like setting a fixed, hard-coded height is a bad idea, because it will restrict the devices that the website can be viewed on. Do you have any suggestions how I could get around this?

Comment: I see your point. However if you want to use a % margin, this % will need a specific size to reference when calculating the margin. You could just always set a fixed margin for #signinGreetText in em/px instead of %...